# i have three tables and when i retrieve data from them i also want to get the table name too

Tags: php, mysql

```
$raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT sno,name,email,phone,smpc FROM existing_sales_details
    WHERE (`sno` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR(`name` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`email` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR  (`phone` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`smpc` LIKE '%".$query."%')
    UNION 
    SELECT sno,name,email,phone,smpc FROM sale_details
    WHERE (`sno` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR(`name` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`email` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR  (`phone` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`smpc` LIKE '%".$query."%')
    UNION
    SELECT sno,name,email,phone,smpc FROM uncharge
    WHERE (`sno` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR(`name` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`email` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR  (`phone` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`smpc` LIKE '%".$query."%')")
    or die(mysql_error());
```

i have three tables and when i retrieve data from them i also want to get the table name to know this data belongs to to this table how can i retrieve the table names according to data please suggest me.

Comment: Stop using the `mysql_*` functions. They have been deprecated since v5.5 (Jun 2013) and removed since v7.0 (Dec 2015). Instead use the [**mysqli_***](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [**PDO**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) functions with [**prepared statements**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) and [**bound parameters**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php).

Comment: What do you mean?! The table name(s) should be known before executing the query?!!!

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)***. Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Answer (score 2):

What you can easily do is:

```
SELECT colum1, column2, 'tableName1' as tableName FROM tableName1
UNION
SELECT colum1, column2, 'tableName2' as tableName FROM tableName2
```

You can always add a string or number as a column in your select. It will be the same for each row.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the issues with the old mysql libraries it's actually fairly easy to return the table name.

Since you are using UNION and essentially 3 selects all you have to do is to the end of each select 
Change

```
 SELECT sno,name,email,phone,smpc
```

To

```
 SELECT sno,name,email,phone,smpc,'XXXX' AS tablename
```

And replace XXXX as the table name in each query